# Screen randomly shuts off on an old iMac 27in

Tags: imac, screen

I am posting a self-answered question to help anyone for an issue I spent several days looking for a solution for, and finally found one.

I had an old non-supported iMac 27in that had the screen shutting off for no apparent reason after some time ranging from a 30 minutes to a few hours to sometimes days. I tried for months to find a pattern, but with no success. My only solution was to reboot the device during this time.

The machine would still be running perfectly, just the screen would not come back no matter what.

I followed all the Apple official and other non-official guides with no success.

I finally found a consistent solution to revive the screen which I posted below. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you give the exact model and OS version? Thanks.

Comment: @benwiggy I currently don't have it in my possession, if I come across it again I will pick it up. If I go from memory I think it was a 2012 model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found that would revive the screen was:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Eject</kbd>

Sometimes I have to press them twice, but it would consistantly work to revive the screen.

Hope it helps!